# Java: Cannot Find Symbol

Tags: java, linked-list, hashmap

Trying to add a `hashmap` entry to a `linkedList` and I get the `"cannot find symbol"` error for the add method.

I have:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


class hash 
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        List<HashMap<String, String>> data = 
        new LinkedList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("name", "demo");
        map.put("fname", "fdemo");

        data.add(0, map);

        String test = map.get("fname");
        String datatest = data.get(0).get("name");

        System.out.println(datatest);

    }

}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: There's no stacktrace for compile errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this to use `Map`, not `HashMap`.

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> data =
new LinkedList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> data = 
        new LinkedList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

Above code Should be: -

```
List<Map<String, String>> data = 
        new LinkedList<Map<String, String>>();
```

Answer (score 1):

because you declared your `map` as a `Map` and not as a `HashMap` you also must declare your `data` as:

```
List<Map<String, String>> data = new LinkedList<Map<String, String>>();
```

you could stick to your List declaration, if you change your `map`:

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> data = new LinkedList<HashMap<String, String>>();
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

But the better way is, whenever possible just use the interfaces and not the specific implementation in the declaration.